# GCM - Old Server key

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a very weird issue in my android app that uses GCM for sending notifications to the user.
Initially, I created a new project on Google console and activated the GCM API. I added the JSON file into my app and my server was sending the notification with the provided API key.

Few days back, I created a new project under a new account. So I got a new JSON file and a new API key for server. I added the new JSON file in my app and added the new API key in my server script. But the issue is, some devices get the notifications with the new key but for some devices, I still need to send the notification using the old API key. These devices have the updated application installed on them.

I am not able to figure why is this happening. I am planning to migrate to FCM soon but still I would like to figure out the reason behind such behavior if in case it repeats in the future.

Comment: For the device that needs your Old API key, is there an error that you receive if you use your new API key? What happens to the notification if you use the new key?

Comment: @KENdi Yes, I get `MismatchSenderID` error.